# Questions seeking commercial extensions

Tags: discussion

A question with a bounty was recently deleted:

[Etsy style multi vendor site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/etsy-style-multi-vendor-site)

I pinged a moderator on Twitter and asked for clarification about deleting questions that have a bounty, as I (mistakenly) believed that bounty questions were immune to delete (close, yes; delete, no).

https://twitter.com/philwinkle/status/356887327030771713

Since that time the question was restored, the bounty is removed.

**So where are we going to draw the line on allowing people to ask questions that they just don't know how to phrase?** I'm sure that @anothershrubery would have used the term ["Marketplace" if they had known that was the phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_marketplace) for an `Etsy-style multi-vendor site`. I think the red flag here was this line:

> I don't want to part with any money for extensions that may not fit
>   the bill, so does anyone have any recommendations

Which suggests the question would end up without a de-facto answer and would primarily be opinion-based. Fair enough.

However with a suggested edit to the question we may have allowed an answer to both inform the user of what this style of shopping experience is called and how to go about implementing within Magento to allow for that type of experience (it is possible with some commercial extensions and without total Admin access. See: http://www.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace).

If we close the door to any question which may result in the recommendation of a commercial extension we may lock ourselves out of ever recommending Enterprise Edition or any full page cache for that matter (as I'm unaware of any free ones worth having).

---

Previously questions about extensions have been allowed:

[Questions about extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/questions-about-extensions)

And certain exceptions have been granted for questions that may require recommendation of a commercial product (careful phrasing required):

[How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162123/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-a-product)

Comment: Voting to close my own question because Ben's answer supports my own case.