# Magmi off topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, extensions

I want to know explicitly if questions that exist only within the scope of Magmi (such that they are only useful to users of Magmi) are off-topic, as a question I posted recently got put on hold as off-topic because it was within the scope of magmi ([Magmi product import with image attributes processor can't find images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102831/magmi-product-import-with-image-attributes-processor-cant-find-images)) I already knew the rule regarding third-party extensions/applications but I know (as stated in this meta post's answer [Questions about extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/questions-about-extensions/74#74)) that if:

"they are an integral part of the Magento landscape, then certainly they should be on topic"

I don't *quite* know what this means but I assumed it meant applications that are popular enough to be considered a must-have install for magento installations and I would consider Magmi exactly that (as the most popular alternative to magento's import functionality).

I was still cautious about posting the question but I finally concluded that it must be on-topic to do so as the magmi tag does exist and includes 153 questions that are mostly within the scope of only magmi (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magmi)
and none of these are off topic and have answers, comments and activity.

So what exactly is the clear rule on posting questions with the magmi tag?
The community behaviour on this seems more than a little confusing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, Magmi questions are on-topic because the source code is readily available.

Comment: That's what I thought but still my question was marked as off, so going forward is it generally accepted that magmi questions aren't implicitly off-topic, how do we come to a point where the community as a large part comes to a consensus on this?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/ Appearantly we can make this happen.

Comment: You'll be hard-pressed to get a Magmi-specific site. I was originally warned that a Magento-specific site wouldn't happen, given the strength of the Magento tag on StackOverflow.

Comment: Not agree with that because if we talk about source code available every `free extension` will be `on topic`.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Exactly. Ideally (and perhaps mandatorily) there is relevant source code provided in the question by OP.

Comment: [Related](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/question-put-on-hold-as-off-topic)

Answer (score 3):

I think Magmi questions should be treated as off topic. If we allow one exception, soon we will have to allow all of them and this website will end up being a cemetery of un-handled extension support questions.
Each developer should support his/her own extensions.
If you have issues using an extension you should address it to the developer.
On the other hand if you ask a question like:

> "I'm using **insert extension name here**, I have **insert problem here**
> with it. Here is the code that is causing my issue:
>
> **insert code here**
>
> Can you help me on this?".
> it should be treated as on topic.

Of course there are some users in here that answer questions about their own extensions.
But they are not too many of them. Even then, the third party extension question should be treated as "off topic", but I have no problem with reopening it if there is a valid answer to it.

Comment: but the point I'm making is that if they are off-topic then we have an issue in that the tag has over a hundred questions in that aren't flagged.

Surely that's a little misleading? What do we do about all those questions?

Comment: Then we have to close those